# How do I select an entire row in a CListCtrlEx

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, dialog, clistctrl

What should be done in order to automatically select one of the rows in a `CListCtrlEx` after it has been filled with data.
The purpose is to select a default row when the `CListCtrlEx` is displayed. For example, if the data shown is a list of cities, to show one of the cities (could be, the previously selected one), selected by default next time the control is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `m_MyList` is part of a dialog, we add the following lines to `OnInitDialog()` and we want to select the first row:

```
m_MyList.SendMessage(LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
m_MyList.SetItemState(0, LVIS_SELECTED | LVIS_FOCUSED, LVIS_SELECTED | LVIS_FOCUSED);
m_MyList.SetFocus();
return FALSE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
```

Don't forget to change the default

```
return TRUE;
```

to

```
return FALSE;
```

Comment: What's the reason for calling `SetFocus`? It's not required for selecting a row. If you do want to set focus for whatever reason, this is [how to set focus in a dialog box](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040802-00/?p=38283). Also, what's with the [ListView_SetItemState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_setitemstate) no-op?

Comment: @IInspectable I use `CDialog::GotoDlgCtrl`.

Comment: *"`ListView_SetItemState(m_MyList, 0, NULL, NULL);` won't work"* - That puzzles me. It is a no-op. It doesn't do **anything**. It's not supposed to do anything either. What are you expecting the message to do that apparently doesn't work?

Comment: @IInspectable, Should have been `ListView_SetItemState(m_Mylist, nItem, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);` see: [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_setitemstate) - and yes. It's not necessary and I removed it.

Comment: @IInspectable I think the problem is OP wants not to see a gray background on the selected item, but a blue one, hence he focused the list control.

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati Why do you use `m_MyList.SendMessage(LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);` instead of `m_MyList.ModifyStyleEx(0, LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);` ?

Comment: @ser `ModifyStyleEx` updates the extended window style. To set an [extended list-view style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/extended-list-view-styles) you have to send an `LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE` message. That said, I don't know *what* the OP is trying to accomplish. To have a list-view's selection mark always visible you'd normally use the `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS` [list-view style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-window-styles).

Comment: Sorry, I meant you could use `m_MyList.SetExtendStyle(m_MyList.GetExtendStyle() | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);`